# Unable to recognize @angular/material?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I'm using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to compile an Angular application and I also added `@angular/material` in the dependencies. I don't know why the compiler wont recognize the dependency I installed.

[image]

Comment: please share the link to the stackblitz instead of the screenshot

Comment: i updated it sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the modules from the correct location

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fix-angular-material-module?file=src/app/app.module.ts) which I forked from your example